# Limitar entrada de caracteres no EditFor em MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Tenho um limitador de caracteres para apenas TEXTO. Agora preciso que os caracteres sejam limitados em apenas 2 (quero fazer com que o usuario digite o estado, por exemplo: PR, SP, RJ...). Como eu faço?

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".apenastexto").keypress(function (event) {
            var inputValue = event.which;                    
            if (!(inputValue >= 65 && inputValue <= 233) && (inputValue != 32 && inputValue != 0)) {
                event.preventDefault();
            }

        });
        $(".apenastexto").addClass("form-control");
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode configurar isso na sua ViewModel utilizando Data Annotation:

```
[StringLength(2, ErrorMessage = "É necessário informar 2 caracteres para a Unidade Federativa.", MinimumLength = 2)]
public string Uf { get; set; }
```

Ou utilizar uma função javascript ativada no click do botão salvar:
    //HTML

```
<button type="button" value="Salvar" onclick="incluiValor(this);">

function incluiValor(sender) {
if ($('#txtUf').val().length < 2 || $('#txtUf').val().length > 2 ) {
    // alerta o usuário, adiciona uma classe css de erro.
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Respondendo a pergunta**

Bem, acho melhor você utilizar o atributo `maxlength`  de um `TextBoxFor`  em vez de `EditorFor`.

`EditorFor` não tem sobrecarga para isto.

Dai basta adicionar isto a sua View:

`@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.uf, new {maxlength = 2})`

**Melhor Solução na minha opinião**

Para mim seria melhor você usar um DropDownList.

Dai basta adicionar isto a seu controller:

```
 List<SelectListItem> uf = new List<SelectListItem>();

 items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Goiás", Value = "GO"});

 items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "São Paulo", Value = "SP" });

 items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Rio de Janeiro", Value = "RJ", Selected = true });

 ViewBag.uf = uf;

 return View();
```

E dai na sua View:

`@Html.DropDownList("uf")`

Da também para criar uma tabela com os estados, e ao invés de popular na "mão", apenas instanciar a classe e enviar para a view.